# Having problem with getting credentials for Google+ API

Tags: google-api, google-plus

After setting the Consent page and enabling Google+ API,

[image]

[image]

when I try to get credentials for this API there is no option to choose Google+ API on the "Add credentials to your project" page.

[image]

Do you have the same problem in the meanwhile or I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That scenario has been expired.
Now I found out that I have to just create an OAuth Client ID
[image]

Select my application type, add my Authorized JavaScript origins, and Authorized redirect URIs manually.

- "Authorized JavaScript origins" are your application base domains that you want to implement external login Js library like
  `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>`
- "Authorized redirect URIs" are the pages that you want to redirect the user after login